# c# Find SelectedRow in Dynamically created DataGridView Inside TabControl

Tags: c#, dynamic, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol and datagridview is created dynamically inside the tabpage of tabcontrol . I need to extract the selected row item values from the active datagridview. The name for this grid would also be dynamically set. what can i do to get the column values from selected row ? Below is the code which is executed in form load event

```
foreach (DataTable dtTable in Ds.Tables)
        {
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
            //dgv.DataSource = dtTable;
            dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode =     System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            dgv.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            dgv.Name = "dgv_" + dtTable.TableName;
            dgv.ReadOnly = true;
            dgv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(725, 322);
            dgv.TabIndex = 0;
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            foreach (DataColumn dtCol in dtTable.Columns)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                column.FillWeight = 1;
                column.Name = dtCol.ColumnName;
                column.DataPropertyName = dtCol.ColumnName;
                dgv.Columns.Add(column);
            }


            //dgv.Columns.AddRange(columns);
            dgv.DataSource = null;
            dgv.DataSource = dtTable;



            lblInfo.Text = string.Format("Rows : {0} ; Columns : {1}", dtTable.Rows.Count, dtTable.Columns.Count);

            TabPage tpInstdata = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            tpInstdata.Controls.Add(dgv);
            tpInstdata.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            tpInstdata.Name = "tp_" + dtTable.TableName;
            tpInstdata.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            tpInstdata.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(725, 322);
            tpInstdata.TabIndex = 1;
            tpInstdata.Text = dtTable.TableName;
            tpInstdata.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            tcInstTab.TabPages.Add(tpInstdata);
}
```

Comment: add code is most helpful

Answer (score 0):

Connect each dgv to the same SelectionChanged eventhandler in your foreach loop:

```
dgv.SelectionChanged += aDataGridView_SelectionChanged;
```

The event handler function could look like this:

```
    private void aDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string aValue = ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedRows[0].Cells["ColumnOfYourInterest"].Value.ToString();
    }
```